# Outlook download attachment macro skips the odd file

Tags: vba, download, outlook, attachment

I have inherited a piece of code that runs from a userform in Outlook 2010.  The code should save all attached files from the selected e-mails in a public folder and save to the users C drive.

The users have assured me (for the last 3 years) that they have to "warm up the macro" first thing in the morning.  They say that if they select 100 e-mails, the macro will ignore some attachments.  However, if they start with 10 e-mails selected, the macro will work.  Then they select 20 on the next run, and keep increasing.

I have managed to replicate this once, but only once, and I can't see why.

Any advice or shared experience would be very much appreciated.

```
Sub DownloadFiles()
Dim objFS As Object
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iLoop As Long
Dim lAttCount As Long, lMessageCount As Long, lngCount As Long
Dim iNameCount As Integer, bContinue As Boolean, lSelCount As Long
Dim strFile As String, strFolderpath As String
Dim lVerCount As Long, bVerNew As Boolean, strVFile As String


'call FSO function to create the local folders if they do not exist
Call TallyFolders

lAttCount = 0
lMessageCount = 0
strFolderpath = "C:\MCSUploads\etally\"

Set objSelection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For lSelCount = 1 To objSelection.Count
    Set objAttachments = objSelection.Item(lSelCount).Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count

    If lngCount > 0 Then

        For iLoop = lngCount To 1 Step -1
            strFile = "No Attachment"
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(iLoop).FileName
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

            If objFS.FileExists(strFile) Then
                'append lSelCount to the filename (not extension) to ensure a unique name
                bContinue = True

                For iNameCount = Len(strFile) To 1 Step -1
                    If bContinue And (Mid(strFile, iNameCount, 1) = ".") Then

                       lVerCount = 1
                       bVerNew = False

                       Do Until bVerNew = True
                            strVFile = Left(strFile, iNameCount - 1) & CStr(lVerCount) & Right(strFile, Len(strFile) - iNameCount + 1)
                            If objFS.FileExists(strVFile) Then
                                lVerCount = lVerCount + 1
                            Else
                                bVerNew = True
                            End If
                        Loop

                        bContinue = False
                    End If
                Next iNameCount

                strFile = strVFile
            End If

            objAttachments.Item(iLoop).SaveAsFile strFile
        Next iLoop
    End If
Next lSelCount

FrmDownloadAttachments1.LblMsg.Visible = True

ExitSub:
Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
End Sub




Sub TallyFolders()
Dim oFileSystem As Object
Dim FolderRaw As String, FolderComplete As String, FolderProblem As String


Set oFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not oFileSystem.FolderExists("C:\MCSUploads") Then oFileSystem.CreateFolder ("C:\MCSUploads")


FolderRaw = "C:\MCSUploads\etally\"
FolderComplete = "C:\MCSUploads\etally\Completed\"
FolderProblem = "C:\MCSUploads\etally\Problems\"
If Not oFileSystem.FolderExists(FolderRaw) Then oFileSystem.CreateFolder (FolderRaw)
If Not oFileSystem.FolderExists(FolderComplete) Then oFileSystem.CreateFolder (FolderComplete)
If Not oFileSystem.FolderExists(FolderProblem) Then oFileSystem.CreateFolder (FolderProblem)



FolderRaw = "C:\MCSUploads\LAR\"
FolderComplete = "C:\MCSUploads\LAR\Completed\"
FolderProblem = "C:\MCSUploads\LAR\Problems\"
If Not oFileSystem.FolderExists(FolderRaw) Then oFileSystem.CreateFolder (FolderRaw)
If Not oFileSystem.FolderExists(FolderComplete) Then oFileSystem.CreateFolder (FolderComplete)
If Not oFileSystem.FolderExists(FolderProblem) Then oFileSystem.CreateFolder (FolderProblem)


FolderRaw = "C:\MCSUploads\MAR\"
FolderComplete = "C:\MCSUploads\MAR\Completed\"
FolderProblem = "C:\MCSUploads\MAR\Problems\"
If Not oFileSystem.FolderExists(FolderRaw) Then oFileSystem.CreateFolder (FolderRaw)
If Not oFileSystem.FolderExists(FolderComplete) Then oFileSystem.CreateFolder (FolderComplete)
If Not oFileSystem.FolderExists(FolderProblem) Then oFileSystem.CreateFolder (FolderProblem)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is very much possible if you do not give the code enough time to save the attachments. The most simple fix is to add `DoEvents` after `objAttachments.Item(iLoop).SaveAsFile strFile`.

The other way is to use `DIR` after that line to check if the file is actually saved.

```
Debug.Print DIR(strFile)
```

Something like this

```
Do While Dir(strFile) = ""
    DoEvents
Loop
```